# Combining arrays within single mongo document with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I am trying to create a call that combines all images between 'images' and 'posts.images' and sorts by createdAt. So far I have:

```
output = [Array(1), Array(3), {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

So it appears to be combining the arrays into a parent array instead of merging into a single array.

What I want:

```
output = [{…},{…},{…},{…},{…},{…},{…},{…},{…},{…},{…},{…}]
```

Here is my schema:

```
const deviceSchema = new Schema({
owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
},
images: [{
    url: {
        type: String,
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
    }
}],
posts: [{
    description: {
        type: String,
    },
    images: [{
        url: {
            type: String,
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
        }
    }],
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
    }
}],
});
```

Here is my aggregate call:

```
const images = await Device.aggregate([
        { $project: {
            combinedImages: { $concatArrays: ["$images", "$posts.images"] }
        }},
        { $match: { _id: id }},
        { $unwind: '$combinedImages' },
        { $sort: { 'combinedImages.createdAt': -1 }},
        { $skip: (page-1)*limit },
        { $limit: limit },
        { $group: { _id: '$_id', images: { $push: '$combinedImages'}}}
    ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `$concatArrays` and `$reduce` to combine all images into a single array, e.g.:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      combinedImages: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$images",
          {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$posts",
              initialValue: [],
              in: {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  "$$this.images"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This leads to the following output:

```
{
    // ...
    "combinedImages": [
      {
        "url": "img1"
      },
      {
        "url": "img2"
      },
      {
        "url": "post_img11"
      },
      {
        "url": "post_img12"
      },
      {
        "url": "post_img21"
      },
      {
        "url": "post_img22"
      }
    ],
    // ...
}
```

See this [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lRWzeWm4c88) to test.